# Open correct message thread on remote notification - iOS Swift Chat application with parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Much like existing chat applications (fb chat, imessages) I want to be able to bring the user to the message thread screen when they respond to a notification banner.

VC hierarchy: TabBarController -> NavController -> MessageThreadsTVC -> MessagesVC

MessageThreadsTVC is a list of contacts essentially, when I click on one, it performs a segue passing an identifier of the selected row to the destination VC, such that it knows which data to pull from the server. Currently no data is persisted on the phone and is all gotten from Parse in the relevant viewDidLoad.

So far I have been able to open the application to the desired tab using:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {


    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive) {

        println("Inactive");

        //Show the view with the content of the push
        // User opened the push notification
        var tabbc:UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as UITabBarController
        tabbc.selectedIndex = 2
```

However how do navigate through 2 more levels of viewController and instantiate the relevant variable in MessagesVC? Where do I have time to query the DB to resolve the matching PFUser object from the objectID string I pass in the remote notification?

Comment: You should add some sort of identifier to the notification payload that tell the app the action you want to do once open.

Comment: My issue is I'm unsure how to create that action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var tabbc:UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as UITabBarController
        tabbc.selectedIndex = 2

        var navVC = tabbc.selectedViewController as UINavigationController

        if (navVC.topViewController.isKindOfClass(MessagesTableViewController)){
            navVC.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
        }
        var topViewController = navVC.topViewController as MessageThreadsTableViewController

topViewController.targetUser = (objects[0] as PFUser)
                            topViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("selectThread", sender: topViewController)
```